# How to remove PostgreSQL 8.4 completely?

Tags: postgresql

I am looking for a way to remove PostgreSQL 8.4 completely? Can any one help me?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming it's installed from packages,

```
sudo apt-get remove postgresql-8.4
```

Or does that not work and you need something more involved? Please post more details if so.

You can get a list of relevant packages to look at removing with:

```
dpkg -l | grep postgresql
```

Comment: while executing sudo apt-get remove postgresql-8.4 im getting developer@vivek:~$ sudo apt-get remove postgresql-8.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  postgresql-8.4
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 15.5MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 136596 files and directories currently installed.)
................
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: That sounds like the basis of a new question - rather than pollute this one, start a new question along the lines of "apt-get remove postgresql-8.4 gives me an error"

Comment: i am getting this error while executing sudo apt-get remove postgresql-8.4  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) pls help me Caesium

Comment: @vivek, please start a new question for it, with 'Ask question' in the top right. The scope of this question has been covered. Alternatively, you can edit the original question to now ask "I'm trying to remove postgresql, but get this error" and paste new appropriate details.. Doing this in comments isn't the best use of this website :)