# How to uninstall Postgresql properly?

Tags: postgresql

I have messed around with the template1 database, and would like to reset everything as it was.

Hence I have done a `sudo apt-get purge postgresql`

However the next time I reinstalled it, the databases are still there. Why? Nothing has been reset.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/82031/how-to-remove-postgresql-8-4-completely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create your databases, the datafiles for this databases are created. These are (of course) not being purged by apt purge.

If `/etc/postgresql/8.4/main/postgresql.conf` (presumably it is not `8.4` - use your version`) still exists, you can find a line like

> data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/8.4/main'         # use data in another directory

There you can find the datafiles for your created databases. If you created your own data directories, I believe you remember where they were.

Does the user `postgresql` still exist? This is the owner of the database files. Delete this user with searching for all his files (use sth like `deluser --remove-all-files`, `man deluser` helps you). If this user does not exist, `find` all files in your filesystem that don't have an associated user and maybe delete them. (Use `find / -nouser -nogroup` -  and again, read `man find`:-) )

For more information, consult [the wonderful postgresql documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to puge and re-install PostgreSQL for that.

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
drop database template1;
create database template1 template template0;
```